# AWS: "ERROR: The request could not be satisfied."

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use `curl` to push my images of my Rails project to my AWS CloudFront distribution with a `POST` request. However I get the following error:

Here is how I made the request:

```
curl --data @general.png http://d2blda41rgubcs.cloudfront.net
```

And this is the error i get:

```
ERROR: The request could not be satisfied
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.
```

I don't know if I need to create a 'Bucket' for my distribution. I also don't know where/if I can set up my distribution to allow this kind of approach to uploading Objects to my distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I have my cloudfront setup to serve the data in my s3 bucket ( and use a command called s3cmd to upload relevant data. )

Comment: would you mind giving a cursory explanation of how to serve an s3 bucket with a cloudfront distribution? I have a hard time understanding the AWS documentation.

Comment: Well Cloudfront is a mirrored CDN which has the capicity for serving files from a closer location to the end user. Typically you would put cloudfront "in front of" your S3 bucket (you would do this when you setup your cloudfront.  S3 is a simple static file storage service... I would say use s3 and a s3cmd to serve your static files until you start to get a grasp all the services provided by AWS.